# Un mot pour spécifier « tous les deux jours » ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps

Pour spécifier *une fois tous les deux mois*, on utilise le terme *bimestriel*.

Existe-t-il un mot (et un seul) pour spécifier *une fois tous les deux jours* ?

Answer (score 3):

Faute de mieux…

Il semble qu'en vieux langage médical (cf. [1](http://books.google.at/books?id=rlNAAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=quotidien+tierce+"tous+les+deux+jours"), [2](http://books.google.at/books?id=IyDMd_wY2EIC&pg=PA18&dq="tous+les+deux+jours"+tierce), [3](http://books.google.at/books?id=MyhFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA638&dq="tous+les+deux+jours"+tierce), [etc](http://www.google.com/#q=quotidien+tierce+%22tous+les+deux+jours%22).), après *quotidien* vient *tierce* (tous les deux jours) puis 
*quarte* (tous les trois jours), *quinte*, etc. La [définition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tierces//2) apparait dans le TLF, qui semble indiquer que le terme est employé uniquement dans un certain domaine médical et vielli.

Comment: Surprenant ! Un terme médical utilisé après-guerre n'a pas perduré jusqu'à nos jours : il serait intéressant de savoir si les médecins proches de la retraite l'ont (bien) connu, pourquoi il n'est plus utilisé un demi siècle plus tard et comment les différentes cyclicités des manifestations infectieuses sont définies de nos jours. Peut-être parce qu'il a une origine plus mathématique que linguistique ?

Answer (score 2):

Dérivé du néologisme **[circadien](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/circadien_circadienne/16118)** (*circa diem*, environ un jour) inventé en 1959 par le chronobiologiste roumain [Franz Halberg](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Halberg), on rencontre parfois « **bi-circadien** » ou « **[bicircadien](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=BICIRCADIEN)** » (environ deux jours), employé essentiellement pour désigner le rythme d'alternance éveil/sommeil parfois observé chez des individus placés dans un environnement sans référence temporelle.

À partir du surprenant **[nycthémère](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/nycth%C3%A9m%C3%A8re#fr)**, on pourrait aussi tenter **binycthéméral**…

Comment: Le mot n'est employé que pour parler de la durée d'un rythme biologique. Autant circadien (rythme d'environ 24 heures) est courant, bicircadien (rythme d'environ 48 heures) est peu usité, et absent de nombreux dictionnaires.

Comment: @Laure, c'est vrai mais la question ne précise pas que le mot doit avoir valeur d'universalité, elle demande seulement un mot et un seul ayant cette signification.

Answer (score 1):

Le faux-ami : *biquotidien* bien que de construction semblable veut dire le contraire, soit deux fois par jour.

Si les professions médicales utilisent *un jour sur deux* c'est  qu'il ne doit pas y avoir de mot, aucune racine latine ou grecque pour exprimer ce rythme qui ne correspond pas à un cycle naturel ou à un cycle rattaché à la lune (comme les semaines dont la durée correspond à une phase de cette dernière).

Comment: Étrange, et dire que *biennal* veut dire « tous les deux ans » et non « deux fois par an ». Quoique cette dernière définition se traduise par *biannuel*.

Comment: @Fauve *Biennal* a été formé comme adjectif sur un nom signifiant une période de deux ans, en latin : *bi-* + *annum* → *biennium* rendu adjectif par un changement de suffixe *biennalis* (lat.) → biennal (fr.). De même *bi-* + *mestre* → bimestre = deux mois, sur lequel est construit l'adjectif *bimestriel*. Les adjectifs de formation plus récentes obéissent à la construction inverse : *bi-* + *mensuel* = deux fois « tous les mois » = deux fois par mois, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne peux pas commenter (merci stack exchange) mais j'aimerais réagir à ce qu'a dit @stéphane-gimenez, donc voici ma réponse (vraie réponse à la question) :

Si ta question est « existe-t-il un mot couramment utilisé et compréhensible » la réponse est non, on dit « tous les deux jours », comme en anglais on dit « the day after tomorrow » même si « overmorrow » existe il est très peu utilisé.

Si tu cherches un mot pour frimer devant ton professeur de français tu peux regarder les autres réponses mais on ne comprendra peut-être pas sans aller chercher un dictionnaire.

Pour « bimestriel », c'est quelque chose qui arrive tous les « bimestres », une période de deux mois. La construction est similaire à « trimestre » (une période de 3 mois), beaucoup plus utilisé.

Pour dire deux fois par mois le mot est « bimensuel ».

Answer (score 1):

D'après [Druide](https://www.druide.com/enquetes/adjectifs-de-p%C3%A9riodicit%C3%A9) qui est très documenté, la réponse est non.

Comment: Bonjour ! Pourquoi ne pas extraire en entier le para. qui commence par : _Il n'y pas d'adjectifs consacrés..._ et référer au site web/Druide sous la citation. Merci.

Comment: Article très interressant, mais je suis d'accord avec @Faʁdɔʃɔtɔmatabaʁwɛt, il vaudrait mieux citer les passage utile et donner la source ensuite